# Build/Run Python Executable in terminal that requires cmd line arguments using Py2app

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, executable, py2app

I have a .py file that is a standalone program that takes in two command line arguments using `argparse`

Followed the following youtube [vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4ykDbciXa8):

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-1", "--Image", required=True, help="Image to be trained on")
    ap.add_argument("-2", "--SaveName", required=True, help="Name of file to be saved")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    image = cv2.imread(args["Image"])
    fileName = (args["SaveName"])
```

The following is my setup.py file for py2app

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['DataTraining.py']
DATA_FILES=[]
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation':True,
    'packages':['certifi'],
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app':OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app ']

    )
```

I can build the program into an applications but when I try to run it in terminal with the command line arguments I have specified it states the inputs as unrecognized options.

This is my terminal execution without args that opens but fails immediately.

```
open DataTraining.app/
```

This is my terminal execution with cmd line args that fails:

```
open DataTraining.app/ --Image /Users/chrisradford/Documents/School/Masters/RA/Classifier/ImageSets/Orig_11.png --SaveName /Users/chrisradford/Documents/School/Masters/RA/Classifier/Python/Orig_11_TrainingAttempt
```

Is there a way to bring in my desired two arguments to execute my program with the terminal? Also if I have my program printing without a GUI will it go to the terminal or will it crash?

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified both arguments as required, it is ok for your app to raise an exception in the first case.  The arg_parse module takes care of that.

Once you have all required arguments supplied, the parsing succeeds but you call a function `vars` that I see no definition of.  This may be a problem, please supply the minimal but complete source code to reproduce it.

Also, what are the error messages you get?  Most of the time there is a good clue in there!

Comment: I don't see where I call vars. The error message is that the arguments provided are not one of the predefined options available

Comment: `args = vars(...)` is a function call.